# nav.popToRoot() showing blank screen

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have 4 page in my app. LoginPage, TransistionPage, FirmsPage and ReportsPage.
If user has already authenticated, my root page is TransistionPage and this page is only responsible for get data from rest and pass it to FirmsPage.

I am trying to go back to root page from ReportsPage(lets assume user has already authenticated and root page is TransistionPage) with nav.popToRoot(), but when I do that I am facing with just white blank page.

//reports page

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-report',
  templateUrl: 'report.html'
})
export class ReportsPage {

  sales: any[];
  collectings: any[];
  summary: any[];
  products: any[];
  loading: any;
  firmId: string;


  constructor() {}

   goBack(){
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
}
```

//Transistion page

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-transistion-page',
  templateUrl: 'transistion-page.html'
})
export class TransistionPage {
  firms: any;
  loading: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public firmService: FirmService) {
    this.getFirms();
    }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello TransistionPage Page');
  }

    getFirms(){
    this.presentLoading();
       this.firmService.getFirms()
       .subscribe(
           data => {
             this.firms = data.subeler;
             //this.loading.dismiss();
             this.navCtrl.push(FirmsPage,{param: this.firms},{animate: true, direction: 'back'});
           },
           error => alert(error),
           () => console.log("firmalar çekildi")
       );
    }


   presentLoading() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Welcome "+window.localStorage.getItem('username')+ " , directing to the firms page",
      duration: 1000,
      dismissOnPageChange: false

    });
    this.loading.present();
  }
}
```

//firms page

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-firms',
  templateUrl: 'firms.html'
})
export class FirmsPage {
  langs;
  langForm;
  loading: any;
  username : string;
  firms: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private navParams: NavParams, public firmService: FirmService, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public authService: Auth) {
     this.firms = this.navParams.get('param');
     this.username = window.localStorage.getItem('username');
     this.langForm = new FormGroup({
      "langs": new FormControl('')
    });
  }


   ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello FirmsPage');
    }

  doSubmit() {
    console.log('Submitting form', this.langForm.value.langs);
    this.navCtrl.push(ReportsPage, {param:this.langForm.value.langs},{animate: true, direction: 'back'});
  }

    logout(): void { 
    this.authService.logout();
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);

    }    
}
```

Normally, requests are working. But, when I popToRoot page don't load I think, it can be releated with where I did the request. I did it in constructor. That's why the page cannot do request when popToRoot. If that's the problem. Where can I do request??

Comment: Did you declare `public navCtrl: NavController` in reports page? Or is it just missing in your snipet?

Answer (score 0):

**You should get a instance of the App to use the popToRoot method**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { App } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {

  navCtrl = this.appCtrl.getRootNav();

  constructor( public appCtrl: App ) { 
    appCtrl.popToRoot();
  }
```